# Should a service be responsible for validating data?

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering what a service should be responsible for. Let's take a UserService which provides a register(email, password) function.

**Option 1**: The Service only makes a call to the api without checking email/password parameters. The checking being done in the controller.

**Option 2**: The Service checks the parameters and then makes the call to the api if the data seems ok. The controller is only calling the service.

I always go for option 1, but maybe it's not the angular way.

Comment: You should do both. Validating on the user side (Angular) will allow you to catch early and not send an unecessary request to your server (as well as providing your user with an early notification). And your server should always validate to handle outside request or prevent tampering.

Comment: Yes of course, but I'm taking only in the angular web app. Do I need to validate the data in the controller or in the service?

Comment: Don't think there's a need to both check data in a controller and a service but agree you do want to have front-end checks and back-end checks for the reasons Simon says.  Form validation from what I've seen is typically done in directives.  It would make some sense in a controller since this works with the view but I don't think it really makes sense in the service (there may be some cases like a service used by many controllers that also has error conditions it needs to report)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use the built-in validation that works with `ng-model`. Using the `ng-pattern`, `ng-requried` (etc.) attributes.

This allows you to validate right at the source of the input, and do things that make the experience better for the user, such as highlighting an invalid field, disabling the submit button, and all that good stuff.

The only advantage of validating in the service itself is that you're able to slightly reduce the amount of code your write, and I guess it's potentially a little more "DRY".

I guess there is a middleground where you define a function on your service that returns true if the input is valid, which you could then use in your form to enable/disable/highlight stuff.

In short, I think the "angular" way of doing it is outside the service, but there's no black or white here - whatever works best for you and your specific implementation.